# comboBox.SelectedItem problem

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox

ComboBox is binding database

```
string str= comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

the line gives `System.Data.DataRowView` value for `str` but not giving selected item name.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem is DataRowView) {
  string sval = ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Row["ColumnName"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` Properties for the combobox before you assign the `DataSource`, and use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`.

For example, if you have a `List<MyClass>` - where `MyClass` has a property `int ID` , and another one `string Title` - and you want to assign it as the `DataSource` of `comboBox1`, you should write:

```
List<MyClass> myList; 
...

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Title";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.DataSource = myList;
```

Now `comboBox1.SelectedValue` is an `object{int}`, which can be casted to `int` and used.

Comment: This gives the index but not the content is written

Comment: that one is SelectedIndex, I am talking about selected value

Comment: private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            label2.Text = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

Comment: lable give {System.Data.DataView}

Comment: @Maziar sharon seems to want to use the selected item of the combobox to populate a label with text ... the problem is not the databinding on the combobox itself ... it's either databinding that label too, or getting the desired text from the selected item

Comment: Would you please explain more where the problem and solution?

Comment: from what i understood you want to get some text from the selected item in the combobox and display that text on some label ... ToString() is the wrong approach here since it will not give you what you want. i see 2 possible solutions here: 1) see my answer on this page (cast the selected item to DataRowView and access the desired column) 2) create a databinding for that label (that's a bit more complicated, you should read up on "databindings")

Comment: Thanks I went to the first approach - Data access works in the field
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want the text of the selected item, just use `comboBox1.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

ToString() is inherited from the Object-Class. The default implementation states the Class Name of the corresponding object.

you may want to cast the SelectedItem to a DataRowView to access the column-values for that row

Ex:

```
String str = ((DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem)["ColumnNameHere"];
```